# Can i handle scroll view in detailViewController using segue prepare function

Tags: ios, swift

Getting below error message

> "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

on this part
all image is no problem.

```
(segue.destination as! DetailViewController).imgView.image = UIImage(named: "horsestar.png")!
```

Below code is whole prepare function

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if segue.identifier == "dog" {
        let imgView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "dogstar.png")!)
        print("dog")

        (segue.destination as! DetailViewController).scrollView.addSubview(imgView)
    } else if segue.identifier == "horse" {
        print("horse")
        (segue.destination as! DetailViewController).imgView.image = UIImage(named: "horsestar.png")!
        (segue.destination as! DetailViewController).scrollView.addSubview((segue.destination as! DetailViewController).imgView)
    } else if segue.identifier == "bear" {
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "bear.png")!)
        print("bear")
    } else if segue.identifier == "eagle" {
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "eagle.png")!)
        print("eagle")
    } else {
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "rabbit.png")!)
        print("rabbit")
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Comment: Its probably because of the image. Check if the png is there

Comment: i checkd image file, image file is okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful with force-unwrapping (!), because it propagates a lot of errors in runtime. If you don't expect `nil` value in your code, user `guard let`.

In your code:

```
(segue.destination as! DetailViewController).imgView.image = UIImage(named: "horsestar.png")!
```

You have two dangerous places:

1. Cast `segue.destination` to `DetailViewController`. If it's impossible, throw `"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"`
2. Load image with name "horsestar.png". If image isn't founded, throw `"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"`

Better use `guard let` (or `if let`):

```
guard let destinationViewController = segue.destination as? DetailViewController else {
    print("unable to get destinationViewController")
    return
}

guard let image = UIImage(named: "horsestar.png") else {
    print("unable to load image")
    return
}

destinationViewController.imgView.image = image
```

Comment: i tried your code. but, it is okay in guard phrase.
but, "destinationViewController.imgView.image = image" is error.
i don't understand..

Comment: Which error do you have? Is your `imgView` not equal nil when you assign image?

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
that error. yes imgView is not equal nil..

Comment: Before calling `viewDidLoad` in `destinationViewController` outlets equal `nil` and the view controller doesn't fully load. Read about ViewControllers lifecycle, because it's very important for developing on iOS platform.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code at `else if` condition

```
else if segue.identifier == "horse" {
    if let toViewController = segue.destination as? DetailViewController {
      toViewController.imgView.image = UIImage(named: "horsestar.png")

     /// your other stuff 
    }
}
```

Still don't know below line  from you code what you want?

```
  (segue.destination as! DetailViewController).scrollView.addSubview((segue.destination as! DetailViewController).imgView)
```

Comment: i want to add subview for scrollView.
so,  scrollView include imageView